# How do I properly handle all edge cases when reading from a PipeReader in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm reading the body of a request in ASP.NET Core 3.1, using Request.BodyReader (which is a PipeReader instance).

In tests, the following seems to work, but frankly the documentation for PipeReader has a couple of warnings in it that I don't understand, so I'm not sure the following is correct.

```
public static async Task ParseRequest(PipeReader bodyReader, CancellationToken requestAborted) {
    while (true) {
        var result = await bodyReader.ReadAsync(requestAborted);
        ReadOnlySequence<byte> buffer = result.Buffer;
        if (result.IsCompleted) {
            try 
            { 
                ProcessRequest(buffer.IsSingleSegment ? buffer.FirstSpan : buffer.ToArray().AsSpan());
            } 
            catch (Exception e)  {
                Logger.Log(e);
            }           
        }

        if (result.IsCompleted || result.IsCanceled || buffer.Length > 1000)
        {
            //If result.IsCompleted, does this matter? 
            //The code here doesn't fully advance if IsCompleted: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/request-response?view=aspnetcore-5.0
            bodyReader.AdvanceTo(buffer.End);
            break;
        } 
        else
        {
            bodyReader.AdvanceTo(buffer.Start, buffer.End);
        }
    }
    //await bodyReader.CompleteAsync(); //<-- is this needed? or not my responsibility?
}
```

Design goals: When the whole body is available, parse the whole thing via ProcessRequest(). If the body is longer than 1000 bytes, ignore the request.

Questions:

1. Do I need to call CompleteAsync() on the PipeReader? I looked at the source code for FormPipeReader, and it never calls Complete on the reader, so I assume this is not necessary (i.e. is done by the framework).
2. The Pipelines [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/pipelines#problematic-code) warns: "Unconditionally calling PipeReader.AdvanceTo with buffer.End in the examined position may result in hangs when parsing a single message. The next call to PipeReader.AdvanceTo won't return until:
   1) There's more data written to the pipe.
   2) And the new data wasn't previously examined."

   - I don't understand what scenario they're describing here. What are the conditions where you should not call PipeReader.AdvanceTo(consumed, buffer.End) when you need more data? In the correct use examples in the same article, they have that exact call in a finally {} block, i.e. unconditionally calling it.
3. Should I call AdvanceTo(buffer.End) when a body has been read, and I've parsed it completely? The example code [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/request-response?view=aspnetcore-5.0#pipelines) does not do so when result.IsCompleted is true, yet the docs also say that not advancing to the end can result in a memory leak. Is it that some other code in ASP.NET ends up taking care of fully consuming the pipe?

Comment: Indeed I confused it with pipes... which are pipes but not pipes... love our naming :) (comment will self-destruct in 9...8...)